# librviz display sensor_msgs/LaserScan

Tags: ros, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i want to use Librviz  (http://pr.willowgarage.com/downloads/groovy-rviz-api-for-review/rviz/html/index.html) in a QT-Gui, subscribe to topic and visualize some data.
I followed the tutorial; http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/librviz_tutorial/html/index.html and it is doing fine. From the tutorial i've got the following:

```
render_panel_ = new rviz::RenderPanel();
lvw->QRvizLayout->addLayout( controls_layout );
lvw->QRvizLayout->addWidget( render_panel_ );
manager_ = new rviz::VisualizationManager( render_panel_ );
render_panel_->initialize( manager_->getSceneManager(), manager_ );
manager_->initialize();
grid_ = manager_->createDisplay( "rviz/Grid", "adjustable grid", true );
```

Now, i want to subscribe to the topic "fts/laserscan_front", which is publishing "sensor_msgs/LaserScan"-Messages. Is there any tutorial out there, how to subscribe to a topic and visualize the messages with Librviz and qt?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191721/librviz-display-sensor_msgs/laserscan/) by [Roman2508](https://answers.ros.org/users/20047/roman2508/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-09-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The same way you created your `rviz::Display* grid_` (assuming this is what you did), you should create an additional display in your code for each corresponding display you would add if you were using RViz itself.

For instance, to add a `LaserScan` display, you should add to your header file:

```
rviz::Display* laser_;
```

Then, in your source file, you should do something like:

```
laser_ = manager_->createDisplay("rviz/LaserScan", "Laser scan", true);
// configure rviz/LaserScan
laser_->subProp("Topic")->setValue("fts/laserscan_front");
laser_->subProp("Style")->setValue("Boxes");
```

You can add the display in RViz and check which settings/properties you would be able to change there. Then just adapt the lines of code above to set the properties you want. The same idea works for any other display type you can add in RViz.

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-02-01**:
It would be great to get an example like this into http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/librviz_tutorial/html/index.html - the grid is too simple, a second tutorial with a `Display` that subscribes to a topic would make things much clearer.

**Comment by [double](https://answers.ros.org/users/31820/double/) on 2017-09-19**:
Hello Lucasw, this link only show one tutorial that librviz shows grid. Could you please provide the second tutorial again?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-09-19**:
I never made a second tutorial, I do have some example code here though: https://github.com/lucasw/rviz_camera_stream/blob/librviz_node/librviz_camera/src/panel.cpp